# Star wars style css3 .jquery effect on scroll / Keyframe effect on mouse scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

Would anyone able to give me any tips on how to create a start wars style text effect that scrolls on mouse scroll?

Basically this:
http://codepen.io/squarecat/pen/KuHsl

controlled by mouse scroll.  If thats at all possible?  I guess realistically this is a wider question on how to trigger keyframes via mouse scroll..

```
@-webkit-keyframes intro {
    0% { opacity: 1; }
    90% { opacity: 1; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Interesting idea, very flaky implementation in my head, but you would tie directly into the scroll event, calculate the distance you are at and apply your opacity accordingly.. Little bit of a headache.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll JS Fiddle example of the fade scroll : http://jsfiddle.net/0ma4na3t/1/